# Elasticsearch : How to retrieve only the desired nested objects

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the below mapping structure for my Elasticsearch index.

```
{
  "users": {
    "mappings": {
      "user-type": {
        "properties": {
          "lastModifiedBy": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lastModifiedDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "details": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "lastModifiedBy": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "lastModifiedDate": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "views": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "properties": {
                    "properties": {
                      "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "value": {
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I want to retrieve ONLY the view object inside details based on index id & view id(details.views.id).

I have tried with the below java code.But seems to be not working.

```
SearchRequestBuilder srq =  this.client.prepareSearch(this.indexName)
    .setTypes(this.type)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_id", sid))
    .setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.nestedFilter("details.views", 
         FilterBuilders.termFilter("details.views.id", id)));
```

Below is the query structure for this java code.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": "123"
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "nested": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "details.views.id": "def"
        }
      },
      "path": "details.views"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example document that you think should be returned by your query, but isn't?

Comment: I've written a ton of ES queries in Java over the past year and here is my advice: don't start by writing your ES queries in Java. I first use SoapUI (it's free) to POST queries to the ES REST endpoint. Once my query is working then I convert it to Java. You could use Poster to send queries through the browser but you'll want to save all your sample queries; Poster only saves one query.

Comment: @SloanAhrens Its basically not returning anything.I am expecting only the individual view object matching the id.

Comment: how does your document with _id 123 look?

Comment: can you explain the use of post_filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `details` is `nested` and `view` is nested inside `details`, you basically need two `nested` filters as well (one for each level) + the constraint on the `_id` field is best done with the [`ids` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html). The query DSL would look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [
        "123"
      ]
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "nested": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "details.view",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "details.views.id": "def"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "path": "details"
    }
  }
}
```

Translating this into Java code yields:

```
// 2nd-level nested filter
FilterBuilder detailsView = FilterBuilders.nestedFilter("details.views", 
    FilterBuilders.termFilter("details.views.id", id));

// 1st-level nested filter
FilterBuilder details = FilterBuilders.nestedFilter("details", detailsView);

// ids constraint
IdsQueryBuilder ids = QueryBuilders.idsQuery(this.type).addIds("123");

SearchRequestBuilder srq =  this.client.prepareSearch(this.indexName)
   .setTypes(this.type)
   .setQuery(ids)
   .setPostFilter(details);
```

PS: I second what @Paul said, i.e. always play around with the query DSL first and when you know you have zeroed in on the exact query you need, then you can translate it to the Java form.